# Python split mp3 channel

Tags: python, mp3

I'd like to seperate the channels of a mp3 file in Python and save it in two other files.
Does anybody know a library for this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Quick google search reveals http://pymedia.org/. I've never used it, but the website says: "It allows you to parse, demutiplex, multiplex, decode and encode all supported formats. It can be compiled for Windows, Linux and cygwin."

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/310765/python-library-to-modify-mp3-audio-without-transcoding

Answer (score 3):

I assume you want to split the channels losslessly, without decoding MP3 and re-encoding it - otherwise you would not have mentioned MP3 at all and would have easily found many tools like **Audacity** to do that.

There are 4 channel modes of MP3 frames - this means 4 types of MP3 files: simple stereo, joint-stereo, dual-channel, mono. joint-stereo files can't be split without loss. mono files doesn't need splitting. The rest: stereo and dual-channel, consists of less than 0.1% of all MP3 files, technically can be split into 2 files, each for a channel, without loss. However there is not any tool on the Internet to do that - not any command line tool nor any GUI tool, because few need the function.

There are not any python library for you neither. Most libraries abstracted MP3 files into a common audio which you can manipulate, after decoding. pymad is the only one specific to MP3 file, and it can tell if a file is using any of the 4 channel modes, but does not offer to extract a channel without decoding it. If you write a new tool, you will have to work on raw MP3 files or produce a library for it.

And it is not easy to write a tool or library for it. It's one stream with 2 channels and not two streams interleaved on a frame level. You cannot simply work on MP3 frames, drop some frames, keep others, and manage to extract a channel out that way. It's a task for a professional, and perhaps best happen in a decoder project (like *lame* or *libmad*) and not in a file manipulation project (like *mp3info* or the python *eyeD3*). In other words, this feature is likely written in C, not python.

---

Implementaiton Note:

The task to build such a tool thus suits well for a computer science C-programming language course project:
1. it takes a lot of time to do;
2. it requires every skill learned from C programming course;
3. it can get wrong easily;
4. it is likely built on the work of other projects, a lesson of adaptating existing work;
5. is a damn-hard endeavor that no-one did before and thus very rewarding
6. perhaps can be done in 300 difficult lines of code instead of bloated simple Visual Basic code, thus is a good lession of modesty and quality;
7. and finally: nobody is waiting in an hurry for a working implementation.

All condition fits perfectly for a C-programming course project.

Implementation Note 2:

some bit-rates are only possible in mono mode (80kbps), and some bit-rates are only possible in stereo mode (e.g. 320kpbs). Luckily this does not present a problem in this task, because all dual-mp3 bit-rate can be mapped into a fitting mono-mp3 bit-rate -- but not vice versa!

Answer (score 0):

The left and right channels are separated from the loaded audio array with `librosa`, the separated channels are saved as new audio files using `soundfile`

```py
import librosa
import soundfile as sf

input_file_path = "your_input_file.mp3"
output_left_path = "output_left.wav"
output_right_path = "output_right.wav"

audio, sr = librosa.load(input_file_path, sr=None, mono=False)

# separate channels
left_channel = audio[0, :]
right_channel = audio[1, :]

# save
sf.write(output_file_left, left_channel, sr)
sf.write(output_file_right, right_channel, sr)
```